# How to make up-left view in Monogame?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coordinates, monogame

You know this from pretty much every up-view game like Towns or Gnomoria.
You can do it, if you just make grid in MS Paint like that:
[image: MSPaint Grid]

(That's also how normal coordination system looks like)
And then hit "Change image" (or something like that) and write in the third and fourth field "50" and "-20" you get away with something like this:

[image: Modified Grid]

How can I make this kind of efect?

Comment: Are you looking for a tilebased isometric engine? or just taking a single texture an skewing it isometrically? You mention towns which would think you want a tilebased system.

Answer (score -1):

OK, pretty much you need to do it the one way that you try out first: Draw one 3D-like tile and then calculate when the next has to be for it to look 3D and then next and so on... You apperently can't dodge this by some grid manipulating.